# $\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}, \text{prove} \,1|a\, \text{and} \,a|0; [(a|b)\land(b|a)]\Longrightarrow a=\pm b; [(a|b)\land(b|c)]\Longrightarrow a|c.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

There is a theorem provided by the text I'm using that shows the following results, and the proofs are left as exercises are left for the reader, i'm just clarifying to make sure I have the right ideas here.

> $$\textbf{Theorem}: a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$$
>   $$(a): 1|a\, \text{and} \,a|0;$$
>   $$(b): [(a|b)\land(b|a)]\Longrightarrow a=\pm b;$$
>   $$(c):[(a|b)\land(b|c)]\Longrightarrow a|c.$$

Proof:

(a): By definition of divisibility, $1|a\iff a=1\cdot n$ for some integer $n$. Take $n=a$, hence $1|a$. Similarly, $a|0 \iff 0=a\cdot n$ for some integer $n$. Take $n=0$, hence $a|0$.

(b): If $a|b$ and $b|a$, then by definition of divisibility, there exists integers $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$ such that:
$$a|b \iff b = a\cdot n_{1}\,\text{and}\, b|a \iff a = b\cdot n_{2}.$$
By substitution, we have  $b=a \cdot n_{1}=(b\cdot n_{2})\cdot n_{1}=b(n_{1}n_{2}),$ and we see that
$$\begin{align}b&=b(n_{1}\cdot n_{2})\\
b-b(n_{1}\cdot n_{2})&=0\\
b(1-n_{1}\cdot n_{2})&=0.\\
\end{align}$$

Which means $b=0$ or $n_{1}\cdot n_{2}=1$. Since $b\neq 0$ (otherwise, the premise is false), it follows that $n_{1}=n_{2}=\pm 1$. Thus, $a=\pm b$.

(c): By definition of divisibility, $a|b \iff b=a\cdot n_{1}$ and $b|c \iff c=b\cdot n_{2}$ for some integers $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$. Since $c=b\cdot n_{2}$, by subsitution, we see that
$$c=b\cdot n_{2}=(a\cdot n_{1})\cdot n_{1}=a\cdot (n_{1}\cdot n_{2}).$$

Let $n'=n_{1}n_{2}.$ Since $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$ are integers and the product of integers is also an integer, it follows that $n'$ is an integer. So $c=a\cdot (n_{1}\cdot n_{2})=a\cdot n',$ and by definition, $a|c$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it looks okay.

Comment: Looks fine, except the arrows in $(a)$ are in the wrong direction (or should be bidirectional). Also if your textbook  allows divisibility by $\,0\,$ (so $\,0\mid n\iff n = 0)\,$ then you need to consider that too in $(b).$

Comment: I thought so as well, but my course oddly defined them simply as implications. Thanks for feedbacks!